# Spark: refresh Delta Table in S3

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql, delta-lake

how can I run the [refresh table](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-aux-cache-refresh-table.html) command on a Delta Table in S3?
When I do

```
deltatable = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, "s3a://test-bucket/delta_table/")
spark.catalog.refreshTable(deltatable)
```

I am getting the error:

```
AttributeError: 'DeltaTable' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'
```

Does the refresh command only work for Hive tables?

Thanks!

Comment: what do you want to achieve with it?

Comment: I have mistakenly deleted some parquet files from the delta table and now I need to bring the delta_log back in sync

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. It's really an incorrect function - the `spark.catalog.refreshTable` function ([doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.Catalog.refreshTable.html#pyspark.sql.Catalog.refreshTable)) is used to refresh table metadata inside the Spark. It has nothing to do with recovery of the Delta table.

To fix this on Delta you need to do something different. Unfortunately I'm not 100% sure about right way for open source Delta implementation - on Databricks we have [FSCK REPAIR TABLE](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/delta-fsck.html) SQL command for that.  I would try following (**be careful, make a backup!**):

- If removed files were in the recent version, then you may try to use [RESTORE command](https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-utility.html#restore-a-delta-table-to-an-earlier-state) with `spark.sql.files.ignoreMissingFiles` set to `true`
- If removed files were for the specific partition, then you can read the table (again with `spark.sql.files.ignoreMissingFiles` set to `true`), leave data only for that partitions, and write data using overwrite mode with `replaceWhere` option ([doc](https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-batch.html#overwrite)) that contains condition
- Or you can read the whole Delta table (again with `spark.sql.files.ignoreMissingFiles` set to `true`) and write it back in Overwrite mode - it will of course duplicate your data, but the old files will be removed by the VACUUM.

Comment: Thanks Alex, your advice solved my problem

Comment: Can you write which of these variants have you used?

Comment: I chose the 3rd option :)